# Editing class private in C++

Tags: c++, class, private

I am working on this code. It is not yet done. The problem is that I do not get why I cannot update `numAccount` in `my simple_account.h`. It just keeps printing out "1" if I print out `numAccount`. Can anyone tell me why I cannot access and change the private value here?

main.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "simple_account.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char job;
    int i = 0;


    while (true) {
        cout << "Job?" << endl;
        cin >> job;
        if (job == 'Q')
            break;
        if (job == 'N') {
            Admin* user = new Admin[10];
            (user+i)->newAccount(i);
            cout << "i: " << i << endl;
            i++;
        }

    }
```

simple_account.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
class Account {
public:
    int id;
    int b = 0;

};

class Admin {
    class Account {
        int id;
        int b = 0;
    };
    int numAccount = 0;
    Account **acnt[10];

public:
    void newAccount();
    void deposit(Account id, int money);
    void withdrawal(Account id, int money);
    void transfer(Account id1, Account id2, int money);
    void check(Account id);
};
```

simple_acount.cc

```
#include "simple_account.h"

void Admin::newAccount() {
        numAccount += 1;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to make the `int id;` member `static` instead of creating it again and again with every `new Account()`?

Comment: what do you mean by member static?

Comment: You'll just start with `0` every time you call `numAccount += 1;`. If you want to create new `numAccount` value for id's you need to have a `static`class member variable that is shared by all `Account` class instances.

Comment: You seem to be creating an awful lot of `Admin`s - ten per account, by my reckoning. You should surely just have one Admin that can create multiple accounts.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs when you press 'N' to open a new account.

```
if (job == 'N') {
            Admin* user = new Admin[10];
            (user+i)->newAccount(i);
            cout << "i: " << i << endl;
            i++;
        }
```

This code creates ten new `Admin` objects, and initializes each one with the default constructor. Each Admin has its own `numAccount` member, which is initialized to zero because that's the default value you specified here: `int numAccount = 0;`
After creating ten `Admin` objects, the code then picks one with `(user+i)` and calls `newAccount(i)`. This should not compile, because the `newAccount()` method does not take a parameter. But if it worked, it would increment that one `Admin`'s `numAccount` member to 1 from the initial 0.
(There's another problem here, which is that when `i` reaches 10, you will be trying to call `newAccount()` on something that's outside your array of `Admin` objects, so you're going to see some **undefined behavior**.)

How to fix this.... depends on what you're trying to do. As suggested, you can make `numAccounts` a `static` member of the `Admin` class. But I think you'll need to review your design: what is an `Admin`, and how many should there be?